# Why isn't my image swap working?

Tags: objective-c, ios

This seems so easy, I'm embarrassed. Every time I trigger this it just stays in the "On" state. it doesn't ever pass the conditional to turn off.

```
-(void) lightbulbSwapImages
{
    NSImage *bulbOn = [NSImage imageNamed: @"sidebar_lightbulb_on.png"];
    NSImage *bulbOff = [NSImage imageNamed: @"sidebar_lightbulb_off.png"];
    if (lightbulb.image = bulbOff)
    [self.lightbulb setImage: bulbOn];
    else
    [self.lightbulb setImage: bulbOff];
}
```

Comment: Is this really an iOS question?  iOS doesn't have an `NSImage` class.  It has `UIImage`.

Comment: You have used assignment operator while checking the condition which assigns the value and evaluates the condition and always finds true and hence you will always have bulbon image. Use == for conditions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `=` with `==`.

```
- (void)lightbulbSwapImages
{
    NSImage *bulbOn = [NSImage imageNamed: @"sidebar_lightbulb_on.png"];
    NSImage *bulbOff = [NSImage imageNamed: @"sidebar_lightbulb_off.png"];
    if (self.lightbulb.image == bulbOff)
       [self.lightbulb setImage: bulbOn];
    else
       [self.lightbulb setImage: bulbOff];
}
```

**Reason behind your issue:**
What you are doing is, trying to assign `bulbOff` to `lightbulb.image` and the result you are checking as a condition which will always return `true` if `lightbulb.image` is not nil. Due to this it will never execute your else part.

It is equivalent to,

```
lightbulb.image = bulbOff;

if (lightbulb.image) {
```

On a side note, if you are using `@property` for `lightbulb`, make it consistent by using the same everywhere including the if condition. In my answer, I have changed from `lightbulb.image` to `self.lightbulb.image`.